# Man pages but for services

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services

Is there a way to see what a certain service is doing when you run the `service --status-all` command? For example, if I wanted to see what whoopsie was after I saw it running, is there a way to find what its purpose is without having to Google for it? I understand it works for some services, i.e. `man xinetd` but I can't find another way when there's no entry and the `-h` flag only displays usage options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other program, most services should come with their own `man` page when installed from your operating system's package repository. To find the correct manual page, try using [`apropos`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/apropos.1.html):

```
$ apropos xinetd
itox (8)             - converts inetd.conf style configuration files to xinetd.conf
xconv.pl (8)         - inetd.conf to xinetd.conf converter
xinetd (8)           - the extended Internet services daemon
xinetd.conf (5)      - Extended Internet Services Daemon configuration file
xinetd.log (5)       - xinetd service log format
```

As you can see, at least on my system (Debian), there are proper manuals pages for `xinetd` and even for its config and log files.

Packages installed from other sources (e.g., `npm`, `pip`) often lack proper manual pages, so you'll have to resort to the world wide web to find the documentation.

Comment: `whoopsie` simply does not have a manual page.  Canonical hasn't written one.  One can find out what it is, with some work.  But [its source package](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~daisy-pluckers/whoopsie/trunk/files) has no manual pages, at all. Ironically, it is part of a subsystem whose aim is "[t]o help Ubuntu reach a standard of quality similar to competing operating systems".  Not by documenting its programs in the manual, it seems.